# Инструменты анализа и фильтрации текста

Tags: php, алгоритм, текст

**Добрый день!**

Не могли бы вы подсказать библиотеки, инструменты (возможно, даже алгоритмы) для фильтрации и анализа текста, созданного человеком?

В общем-то, буду рад любым вашим подсказкам, связанным с фильтрацией и анализом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите [phpMorphy](http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/). Так же есть [mystem](http://api.yandex.ru/mystem/) и [томита-парсер](http://api.yandex.ru/tomita/) от яндекса, но они не на php.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ну а что касается MYSTEM, так это ведь консольная программа, а в PHP можно с консолью взаимодействовать.

Comment: @Heisenberg, конечно можно, просто в вопросе был озвучен php.